# Scheduling a task into a period within a day, depending on whether or not it is a weekend

Tags: c++, c++11, datetime

I have a function which needs to detect part of the day depending on whether it's the weekend or not (the weekend affects the lunch time indication). The method is quite long and I'd like to know how it can be better.

```
double PartOfDayRule::ExtractFeature(dto::ActionableItem & item) {
                double morning, firstWorkPart, lunch, secondWorkPart, afterWork, beforeSleep, sleepTime;
                morning = 0;
                firstWorkPart = 1;
                lunch = 2;
                secondWorkPart = 3;
                afterWork = 4;
                beforeSleep = 5;
                sleepTime = 6;

                double result = -1;
                dto::DateTime itemTime = item.scheduledStart;
                if(util::time::inRange(item.ctx->sleepTimeEnd, item.ctx->workTimeStart, itemTime)){
                    result = morning;
                    goto result;
                }

                dto::DateTime lunchStart;
                dto::DateTime lunchStop;
                if(!item.ctx->isWorkingDay){
                    lunchStart = item.ctx->workTimeStart;
                    lunchStop = item.ctx->workTimeFinished;
                }else{
                    long firstWorkPartLength = util::time::between<std::chrono::hours>(item.ctx->workTimeStart, item.ctx->workTimeFinished) / 2;
                    lunchStart = item.ctx->workTimeStart + std::chrono::hours{firstWorkPartLength};
                    lunchStop = lunchStart + std::chrono::hours{1};
                }
                if(util::time::inRange(lunchStart, lunchStop, itemTime)){
                    result = lunch;
                    goto result;
                }

                if(util::time::inRange(item.ctx->workTimeStart, lunchStart, itemTime)){
                    result = firstWorkPart;
                    goto result;
                }

                if(util::time::inRange(lunchStop, item.ctx->workTimeFinished, itemTime)){
                    result = secondWorkPart;
                    goto result;
                }

                dto::DateTime sleepPreparationTime = item.ctx->sleepTimeStart - std::chrono::hours{1};
                if(util::time::inRange(item.ctx->workTimeFinished, sleepPreparationTime, itemTime)){
                    result = afterWork;
                    goto result;
                }

                if(util::time::inRange(sleepPreparationTime, item.ctx->sleepTimeStart, itemTime)){
                    result = beforeSleep;
                    goto result;
                }

                result = sleepTime;
                result:
                return result;

            }
```

Answer (score 4):

You return what is effectively an enum as a double. Why? create the enum and return that it's much clearer that way wat the return value means:

If you still want a single point of return (for whatever reason) then you can use an if-else chain:

```
enum PartOfDay{
    morning = 0,
    firstWorkPart = 1,
    lunch = 2,
    secondWorkPart = 3,
    afterWork = 4,
    beforeSleep = 5,
    sleepTime = 6
}

PartOfDay PartOfDayRule::ExtractFeature(dto::ActionableItem & item) {

    dto::DateTime lunchStart;
    dto::DateTime lunchStop;
    if(!item.ctx->isWorkingDay){
        lunchStart = item.ctx->workTimeStart;
        lunchStop = item.ctx->workTimeFinished;
    }else{
        long firstWorkPartLength = util::time::between<std::chrono::hours>(item.ctx->workTimeStart, item.ctx->workTimeFinished) / 2;
        lunchStart = item.ctx->workTimeStart + std::chrono::hours{firstWorkPartLength};
        lunchStop = lunchStart + std::chrono::hours{1};
    }

    dto::DateTime itemTime = item.scheduledStart;
    dto::DateTime sleepPreparationTime = item.ctx->sleepTimeStart - std::chrono::hours{1};
    PartOfDay result = sleepTime;

    if(util::time::inRange(item.ctx->sleepTimeEnd, item.ctx->workTimeStart, itemTime)){
        result = morning;
    } else if(util::time::inRange(item.ctx->workTimeStart, lunchStart, itemTime)){
        result = firstWorkPart;
    } else if(util::time::inRange(lunchStart, lunchStop, itemTime)){
        result = lunch;
    } else if(util::time::inRange(lunchStop, item.ctx->workTimeFinished, itemTime)){
        result = secondWorkPart;
    }else if(util::time::inRange(item.ctx->workTimeFinished, sleepPreparationTime, itemTime)){
        result = afterWork;
    }else if(util::time::inRange(sleepPreparationTime, item.ctx->sleepTimeStart, itemTime)){
        result = beforeSleep;
    }else {
        result = sleepTime;
    }
    return result;

}
```

Or you can sort the ranges and then use `std::find` to get the range you want.

Answer (score 4):

I would create a `range` structure to hold each range you care about, along with the value to associate with each, then search through that.

I'd also use an enumeration for the names of the parts of the day (`double` doesn't seem to make any real sense for this task).

IMO, anytime you're using `std::chrono`, it's worth considering using a namespace directive to bring it into scope.

Putting those together, we'd end up with code something on this order:

```
enum result_type { morning, firstWorkPart, lunch, secondWorkPart, afterWork, beforeSleep, sleepTime };

struct range {
    double begin;
    double end;
    result_type result;
};

double PartOfDayRule::ExtractFeature(dto::ActionableItem & item) {
    dto::DateTime lunchStart;
    dto::DateTime lunchStop;
    if (!item.ctx->isWorkingDay) {
        lunchStart = item.ctx->workTimeStart;
        lunchStop = item.ctx->workTimeFinished;
    }
    else {
        using namespace std::chrono;
        long firstWorkPartLength = util::time::between<hours>(item.ctx->workTimeStart, item.ctx->workTimeFinished) / 2;
        lunchStart = item.ctx->workTimeStart + hours{ firstWorkPartLength };
        lunchStop = lunchStart + hours{ 1 };
    }

    std::vector<range> ranges{
        { item.ctx->sleepTimeEnd, item.ctx->workTimeStart, morning},
        { lunchStart, lunchStop, lunch },
        { item.ctx->workTimeStart, lunchStart, firstWorkPart },
        { lunchStop, item.ctx->WorkTimeFinished, secondWorkPart },
        { item.ctx->workTimeFinished, sleepPreparationTime, afterWork },
        { sleepPreparationTime, item.ctx->sleepTimeStart, beforeSleep }
    };

    for (auto const &r : ranges)
        if (inRange(r.begin, r.end, itemTime))
            return r.result;
    return sleepTime;
}
```

The loop *could* also be written using `find_if`, but I'm not sure it provides a real improvement:

```
auto pos = find_if(ranges.begin(), ranges.end(), 
    [=](auto r) { return inRange(r.begin, r.end, itemTime); });
if (pos != ranges.end())
    return pos->result;
return sleepTime;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can return at any point of the method and it will end, so there is no need to use goto (which is a bad idea most of the time). You can also delete some braces and fix the indentation.

```
double PartOfDayRule::ExtractFeature(dto::ActionableItem & item) {
    double morning, firstWorkPart, lunch, secondWorkPart, afterWork, beforeSleep, sleepTime;
    morning = 0;
    firstWorkPart = 1;
    lunch = 2;
    secondWorkPart = 3;
    afterWork = 4;
    beforeSleep = 5;
    sleepTime = 6;

    double result = -1;
    dto::DateTime itemTime = item.scheduledStart;

    if(util::time::inRange(item.ctx->sleepTimeEnd, item.ctx->workTimeStart, itemTime))
        return = morning;

    dto::DateTime lunchStart;
    dto::DateTime lunchStop;

    if( !item.ctx->isWorkingDay ){
        lunchStart = item.ctx->workTimeStart;
        lunchStop = item.ctx->workTimeFinished;
    } else {
        long firstWorkPartLength = util::time::between<std::chrono::hours>(item.ctx->workTimeStart, item.ctx->workTimeFinished) / 2;
        lunchStart = item.ctx->workTimeStart + std::chrono::hours{firstWorkPartLength};
        lunchStop = lunchStart + std::chrono::hours{1};
    }


    if(util::time::inRange(lunchStart, lunchStop, itemTime))
        return lunch;

    if(util::time::inRange(item.ctx->workTimeStart, lunchStart, itemTime))
        return firstWorkPart;

    if(util::time::inRange(lunchStop, item.ctx->workTimeFinished, itemTime))
        return secondWorkPart;

    dto::DateTime sleepPreparationTime = item.ctx->sleepTimeStart - std::chrono::hours{1};
    if(util::time::inRange(item.ctx->workTimeFinished, sleepPreparationTime, itemTime))
        return afterWork;

    if(util::time::inRange(sleepPreparationTime, item.ctx->sleepTimeStart, itemTime))
        return beforeSleep;

    return sleepTime;

}
```

Comment: I'd also add that you can declare and initialize a variable on the same line (and with one per line), that constants should me marked as such and that so long function may be broken into smaller more self-descriptive snippets.